# Non italic text in math formula inside remark

Tags: fonts, formatting

I use some text in the math formula, e.g.:

```
$ \texttt{MinimumPolynomial}(T) \mid \texttt{CharacteristicPolynomial}(T)$.
```

I use "\texttt" to make such text non-italic.

This works fine but, when I use remark to wrap around it, e.g.

```
\begin{remark}
This is a remark:
$ \texttt{MinimumPolynomial}(T) \mid \texttt{CharacteristicPolynomial}(T)$. 
\end{remark}
```

, all text are italic now.

I wish the text outside of math formular, e.g. "This is a remark", still be italic, while the ones inside, e.g. "MinimumPolynomial" be straight.

How could I do that?

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Put `\normalfont` after `\begin{remark}` like `\begin{remark}
\normalfont`

Comment: Please share the code of how the `remark` environment is set up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\text....`  commands escape to text mode so use the current *text* font settings. Math fonts do not change according to the local context and here you want the math monospace font so use `\mathtt{MinimumPolynomial}`

Comment: but \mathtt will ignore the spaces inside it, is it?

Comment: @athos do you really have spaces in function names?

Comment: it's a minor thing, for example I use \texttt{sgn } \sigma to keep a bit space between the text part and other symbol parts in a math formular. but i can use \mathtt{sgn\,}, so no problem.

Comment: @athos no! don't do either of those things:-) `\mathop{\mathtt{sgn}}` will give the same space as `\log` so small space in `\sgn x` but no space in `\sgn(x)`

Comment: some little new things to learn :)